# Is the trait Owner useful in unit tests?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

In 2012, Visual Studio has introduced the concept of trait, as described in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-unit-tests-with-test-explorer).

One of the attributes is the [Owner trait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.ownerattribute(v=vs.140).aspx) that specifies the person responsible for a test method.

I would like to know if it is recommended to use this trait or not. My primary intuition will be to **ignore this feature because of the collective code ownership principle**.

So my question is : what are the reasons we should use (or not) the `Owner` trait in Visual Studio unit testing framework ?

Answer (score 3):

Your question can be broadened and applied to all forms of program source code.

On a large team it can be useful to have a reference naming a first point of contact, however such information is liable to become out of date. The source control commit history provides a more dynamic view of code familiarity/ownership but non technical QA people might not be familiar with these tools.

There is no right or wrong, it is a local cultural team decision.